# UICollectionView reload data doesn't work on IOS7 when datasource number changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

1. It only happen when the # of items changed.
2. If I delay for 30 seconds, it works. But too long.

When I reload the data and I am getting terminating app due to:

```
uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with 
an index path that does not exist: 
<NSIndexPath: 0x15f766e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}
```

Code:

```
-(void)loadCV{
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAWParsePostsClassKey];
    query.limit = 5;

    NSArray *objects = [query findObjects];

    self.data = nil;
    self.data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
    self.CurrentPage = 1;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   [self.cv reloadData];
                   [self.cv.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];   
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you making sure your UICollectionView delegates are updating correctly? numberOfItemsInSection comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I know It's rather old, but for some who have arrived here:

`[self.cv reloadData]` should be called from main thread.